# How to check if there is initial value and duplicate entry?

Tags: abap

I have an ABAP program to add records into the database. I would like to check if there is the same identification number in the database and if so raise an error message. The second thing, if user passes the id field as empty I would like to raise an error message.

MY METHOD TO ADD RECORDS INTO DATABASE

```
    METHOD add.
        DATA: IT_E TYPE TABLE OF ZE.
        DATA:WA_E TYPE ZE.
    IF sy-subrc EQ 0.

        WA_E-ID = C_ID.
        WA_E-NAME = C_NAME.

        APPEND wa_e TO it_e.
        INSERT ZE FROM TABLE it_e.

         CALL FUNCTION 'POPUP_TO_DISPLAY_TEXT'
          EXPORTING
          TITEL     = 'Message2'
          TEXTLINE1 = 'Record Added Successfully.'.
      IF sy-subrc <> 0.
    CALL FUNCTION 'POPUP_TO_DISPLAY_TEXT'
          EXPORTING
          TITEL     = 'Message2'
          TEXTLINE1 = 'YOu cant use this id no'.
      ENDIF.


DATA : ref_obj TYPE REF TO LCL_E.
```

MAIN PART

```
START-OF-SELECTION.
  IF ra_add EQ 'X'.

IF pa_id eq space.

     CALL FUNCTION 'POPUP_TO_DISPLAY_TEXT'
      EXPORTING
      TITEL     = 'Message2'
      TEXTLINE1 = 'You cant pass id field empty'.
else.
    CREATE OBJECT ref_obj
      EXPORTING
        im_id = pa_id
        im_name  = pa_name


CALL METHOD ref_obj->add.

endif.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first issue I would recommend to make a SELECT with the key before the INSERT to ensure that record exists in table, if it does display the message else make the INSERT. For the second issue you should use "IF lv_data IS INITIAL".

Answer (score 0):

1)You can make the field mandatory using the keyword OBLIGATORY.

PARAMETERS : pa_id type c OBLIGATORY.

2) Try to retrieve the record from database using the id.if the sy-subrc <> 0 then insert the record ,else raise the error message.